# ibatis returns NULL for "Insert" command, instead of the number of affected rows

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis, ibatis

Using ibatis with MySQL, created a mapper interface as follow:

```
INSERT INTO <_tableName>(<listOfFieldsNames>) SELECT <listOfValues> FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM <_tableName> WHERE <condition>);
```

Jhe java interface is set to return Integer, as I want to get the number of affected rows.

The thing is that it always return NULL.

Any idea how to fix it so I'll get the number of affected rows...?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can only talk about MyBatis, not Ibatis, but I would suggest returning `int`, not `Integer`. The number of rows inserted is 0 if nothing, not `null`. See also the [Java documentation](https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/java-api.html#Statement_Execution_Methods) for MyBatis.